# "right shift" in $L^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $X=L^1(\mathbb{R})$ be the space of Lebesgue integrable functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with the usual norm.

Let $T\in B(X)$ be defined by

$$(Tf)(t)= f(t+1)$$

I need to find the point spectrum, the approximate point spectrum and the spectrum itself.

I can show that $T$ defines a linear bijective isometry, so its spectrum is inside the set $\{ \lambda \in \mathbb{C} : | \lambda |=1 \}.$

Thanks to Daniel Fisher's help I can go further:

The point spectrum 
$\sigma_p(T) = \varnothing.$

Since $f(t) = \lambda f(t+1) \implies |f(t)|=|f(t+1)|\ \ \ \ \ \ \forall t $

But the only periodic integrable function is zero.

Now, the adjoint of $T$ is the "left shift" and similarly we show that its point spectrum is empty.

But the spectrum of $T$ is non empty and $\sigma(T)=\sigma_{ap}(T) \cup \sigma_p(T')$

Therefore there exist $\lambda$ s.t. $|\lambda| =1$ and a sequence $f_n$ of unit norm elements in $X$ s.t. $||\lambda f_n-Tf_n|| \rightarrow 0$

Hence taking $g_n=e^{i\rho} f_n$ for suitable $\rho$ we conclude that

$\sigma(T)=\sigma_{ap}(T)=\{ \lambda \in \mathbb{C} : | \lambda |=1 \}$

Could anyone please confirm whether or not my reasoning makes sense?

I will accept any answer explaining if it is right or what I did wrong!

This is not homework, thank you.

Comment: A similar argument shows that the point spectrum is empty.

Comment: @DanielFischer fisher and then I would also have that the point spectrum of the adjoint is empty, but the spectrum can't be empty. I think there is some simmetry going on here, I might be wrong but it seems to me that each of these points on the unit circle is "equivalent" so that the spectrum has to be the all circle... I'm probably just not making any sense

Comment: If we had $f(t+1) = e^{i\varphi} f(t)$ (almost everywhere), then $\lvert f\rvert$ would be periodic, hence $f = 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks, after your first comment I got that part (just need to take modulus in the equality) I am not sure how to proceed though: is the first step to say that the spectrum is non empty? then the approximate point spectrum is non empty (since the point spectrum of the adjoint is empty) and hence I guess I can show that if there is one element of the approximate point spectrum, then rotating it I can get that the all unit circle is in the point spectrum.

Comment: point spectrum is the set of $\lambda$ s.t the kernel of $\lambda I - T$ is non trivial. so far we have determined that the point spectrum of $T$ is empty. I don't think T-1 is invertible neither, my previous comment was an attempt to prove that by using the fact that the spectrum of an operator is equal to its approximate point spectrum union its adjoint's point spectrum. (this was in response to somebody else's comment, now disappeared!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(Tf)(t)=f(t+1)$ defines a unitary operator with inverse $(T^{\star}f)(t)=f(t-1)$. So the spectrum of $T$ is contained in the unit circle. Neither $T$ nor $T^{\star}$ has any point spectrum, which you have discovered. So $(T-e^{i\theta}I)$ and $(T^{\star}-e^{i\theta}I)$ have dense ranges for all $0 \le \theta < 2\pi$ because
$$
         \mathcal{R}(T-e^{i\theta}I)^{\perp}= \mathcal{N}(T^{\star}-e^{-i\theta }I)=\{0\}.
$$
Nothing above excludes any of these ranges from being all of $X$ so far. However, that is not the case because every $e^{i\theta}$ is in the continuous spectrum of $T$ (and $T^{\star}$). To see this, consider
$$
    f_{\rho,\theta}(t) = \exp\{-\rho|t|+i\theta t\},\;\;\; \rho > 0,\; 0\le \theta < 2\pi.
$$
Notice that
$$
         Tf_{\rho,\theta}-e^{-i\theta}f_{\rho,\theta}  =(e^{-\rho|t|}-e^{-\rho|t+1|})e^{i\theta t}.
$$
A direct calculation shows that
$$
                     \lim_{\rho\downarrow 0}\frac{\|(T-e^{-i\theta}I)f_{\rho,\theta}\|}{\|f_{\rho,\theta}\|}=0.
$$

Comment: thanks, is this a standard function to think of in these cases?

Comment: It's one way to approximate $e^{i\theta t}$, which is something you have to do in order to get an approximate eigenfunction. And the approximation should have a translation property in order to make calculations possible, which definitely suggests an exponential.

Comment: By the way, your new solution is correct.

Comment: are you sure it is? How do we know that the approximating sequence $f_n$ has the required translation property? thanks again!

Comment: Show that $\|(T-e^{i\theta}\lambda I)(e^{i\theta t}f_{n})\|=\|e^{i\theta t}(e^{i\theta}T-e^{i\theta}\lambda I)f_{n}\|=\|(T-\lambda I)f_{n}\|$.